# External css page not working

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have created a jsp file called top.jsp and a css file called top.css. My problem is that my top.jsp doesn't show the background color specified in top.css.

Code in top.css

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

body { 
    background-color: blue; 
    }
```

Code in top.jsp

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/top.css"/>
```

What do I need to do in order to make the background color blue?

Here is a picture of my file structure:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/top.css"/>` statement is looking for a css folder inside the *same* folder as the `top.jsp` file. This means it's looking for your css in the wrong place: currently it's looking for -> `/jsp/css/top.css`

You actually want it to go up one level in the folder structure to be in the webapp folder and then into the css folder so you need to change your href to `href="../css/top.css"` (the `..` takes you up to the webapp folder and out of the jsp folder).